# MvvmCross: How to programmatically construct an MvxListView with custom adapter?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to implement a grouped listview on Android similar to iOS.  Therefore, I am trying to write my own custom MvxAdapter that supports grouped section headers.  The default MvxListView constructed from axml will create a default MvxAdapter.  Since I need to supply my own custom MvxAdapter, I need to create the MvxListview programmatically so I can pass in my own adapter.  The problem I am having is at the time of `OnCreate` of my android view where I try to construct my custom MvxAdapter, the Android binding context is null as retrieved from

```
MvxAndroidBindingContextHelpers.Current()
```

Is there an example of constructing an MvxListView programmatically with a custom MvxAdapter with v3 API?

Comment: The MvxActivity has a BindingContext property, should I just use that to pass into my custom MvxAdapter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no examples of creating an MvxListView programatically - almost all Android UI controls are created in axml in the current samples.

For creating custom adapters, there are a few examples around, inclduing:

- an example in the polymorphic list in the collection at: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Working%20With%20Collections
- an advanced example in the https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.UI.Droid/Views/SessionsLists/BaseSessionListView.cs

---

Alternatively, you can, of course, inherit a `CustomListView` from `MvxListView` and can then pass in your custom adapter as part of the constructor.

For more on creating and using custom views, see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/n18-android-custom-controls-n1-days-of.html

---

In the event that you ever do want to push a context onto the stack you can do this using:

```
  using (new MvxBindingContextStackRegistration<IMvxAndroidBindingContext>(**TheContext**))
  {
      // create your controls here
  }
```

This is exactly what happens during xaml inflation - see: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/BindingContext/MvxAndroidBindingContext.cs#L47

Comment: thanks, by the way, can you make GetPosition in MvxAdapter virtual for easier overriding?

Comment: This isn't what SO comments are for. http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/p/if-youve-got-questions.html