# Android Fragment: View fully from code causes binding to null-object

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvmcross

I have quite a few fragments, that are 90% common in layout. And because I really like layout from code (I never create XIBs for iOS anymore), I thought: lets do the same for Android. That was not as easy as I thought it would be. The trouble is in MvvmCross, and after scouring the web for solutions, only hints pointing to the solution can be found.

The problem: when the fragment is displayed, and I perform the binding, I get all messages the source property cannot be found because it tries to bind to a null-object.

```
Unable to bind: source property source not found Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.PropertyPath.PropertyTokens.MvxPropertyNamePropertyToken on null-object
```

The layout is displayed on screen, the ViewModel is set, the bindingcontext is set (both created by myself, because that was not done automatically).

I suspect something is done in inflation to 'register'  the created controls, and because I do not use inflation, they are not registered. I read in other questions about the MvxBindingContextStackRegistration, watched the sources for that. 
Second cause might be the bindingcontext itself: somehow it is not handled automatically, and that points to something necessary missing beging called in the below code.

I might have done some strange thing, because this is the final attempt to get it working:

```
    public class IndexTocFragment : MvxFragment
{
            // two statics to save on typing
    public static int WRAP = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent;
    public static int FILL = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent;
    public LinearLayout NewVerticalLinearLayout(Orientation orientation, Boolean fillparent) {
        var ll = new LinearLayout (Activity) { Orientation = orientation };
        ll.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (FILL, fillparent ? FILL : WRAP);
        return ll;
    }


    public new IndexTocViewModel ViewModel { get { return base.ViewModel as IndexTocViewModel; } set { base.ViewModel = value; } } 

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var layout = NewVerticalLinearLayout (Orientation.Vertical, true);


        if (ViewModel == null)
            ViewModel = Mvx.IocConstruct<IndexTocViewModel> ();
        BindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext (Activity, new MvxSimpleLayoutInflater(inflater));
        using (new MvxBindingContextStackRegistration<IMvxAndroidBindingContext>(((IMvxAndroidBindingContext) this.BindingContext)))
        {
            //var layout = NewVerticalLinearLayout (Orientation.Vertical, true);
            layout.SetBackgroundColor (Color.ParseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            var titlelayer = NewVerticalLinearLayout (Orientation.Horizontal, false);
            titlelayer.LayoutParameters.Height = 40;
            var title = new TextView (Activity) { LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (FILL, FILL) };
            title.SetTextColor (Color.ParseColor ("#212121"));
            var titlebutton = new Button (Activity) { LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (WRAP, FILL) };
            titlelayer.AddView (title);
            titlelayer.AddView (titlebutton);
            layout.AddView (titlelayer);

            var twobuttonlayer = NewVerticalLinearLayout (Orientation.Horizontal, false);
            twobuttonlayer.LayoutParameters.Height = 40;
            var twobuttonklein = new Button (Activity) { LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (FILL, WRAP) };
            twobuttonklein.Text = "Klein";
            twobuttonklein.SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.kleingrootbutton);
            var twobuttongroot = new Button(Activity){ LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (FILL, WRAP) };
            twobuttongroot.Text = "Middel/groot";
            twobuttongroot.SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.kleingrootbutton);
            twobuttonlayer.AddView (twobuttonklein);
            twobuttonlayer.AddView (twobuttongroot);
            layout.AddView (twobuttonlayer);

            var zoekvak = new EditText (Activity) { LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (FILL, WRAP) };
            zoekvak.Hint = "Zoek in inhoudsopgave";
            layout.AddView (zoekvak);

            var emptytext = new TextView (Activity) { LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (FILL, WRAP),
                Text = "Er zijn geen resultaten." };
            emptytext.SetBackgroundColor (Color.ParseColor ("#BBAA00"));
            layout.AddView (emptytext);

            var listadapter = new BindableExpandableListAdapter(this.Activity, (IMvxBindingContext) BindingContext);

            var list = new BindableExpandableListView (Activity, null, listadapter) { LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (FILL, FILL) };
            list.SetMinimumHeight (50);
            list.ItemTemplateId = Resource.Layout.indextocsectionlistitem;
            list.GroupTemplateId = Resource.Layout.indextocitem;
            list.SetGroupIndicator (null);
            list.SetBackgroundColor (Color.ParseColor ("#AAAA00"));
            layout.AddView (list);
            this.DoBind += () => {
                var bs = this.CreateBindingSet<IndexTocFragment, IndexTocViewModel> ();

                if (ViewModel == null) { 
                    Console.WriteLine ("ERROR ViewModel not set"); 
                }
                if (BindingContext == null) { 
                    Console.WriteLine ("ERROR BindingContext not set"); 
                }

                bs.Bind (title).For (x => x.Text).To (vm => vm.IndexTitle);
                // the following title displays some data from the ViewMode, and that works OK.
                                    Console.WriteLine("Index title value: "+ViewModel.IndexTitle);
                bs.Bind (twobuttongroot).For ("Click").To (vm => vm.SwitchKleinGrootCommand);
                bs.Bind (twobuttonklein).For ("Click").To (vm => vm.SwitchKleinGrootCommand);
                bs.Bind (zoekvak).For (x => x.Text).To (vm => vm.SearchText);
                bs.Bind (emptytext).For (x => x.Text).To (vm => vm.TextForEmptyList);
                bs.Bind (listadapter).For(x => x.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.Chapters);
                bs.Apply ();                
            };
                            // the next binding was never called
            //this.DelayBind (() => {
            //
            //});

        }



        //var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.IndexTocView, null);
        Console.WriteLine ("LAYOUT RETURNED");

        return layout;
    }

    private Action DoBind;


    public override void OnResume()
    {
        // doing the binding here to make sure everything should have been set,
        but it is of course not the logical location
        base.OnResume();
        Console.WriteLine ("RESUMING");
        if (DoBind != null)
            DoBind ();

    }



}
```

For now I will create a fragment layout with everyting I need, and hide the elements that are not needed, that will probably work. But I hope I can use creating views from code.

Thanks for helping.

BTW: the code from the activity and presenter is the custom presenter code taken from the fragments example in MvvmCross.
Binding in code for Android: [MVVMCross for android - how to do binding in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724278/mvvmcross-for-android-how-to-do-binding-in-code)
Pushing a context on the stack: [MvvmCross: How to programmatically construct an MvxListView with custom adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760196/mvvmcross-how-to-programmatically-construct-an-mvxlistview-with-custom-adapter)

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED

Sigh. Not the first time this happens a few minutes after finally asking it here after hours of frustration..

Solved it (at least it is working now):

```
        BindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext (Activity, new MvxSimpleLayoutInflater(inflater), ViewModel);
```

In my code the last parameter was not provided. So probably the binding context was not fully set.

In MvvmCross code I found some warning that EnsureBindingContext was not working...

Now testing if the delaybind is working again...